# How to convert a image/tiff;base64 string to image/png;base64 string?

Tags: html, .net, imageview

In trying to convert a base64 tiff image to base64 png. I'm not able to view the image when it is in base64 tiff string.

Answer (score 0):

open it in a browser with a HTML tag, use JS to create on and pass the value.

then use screen shot,

Command + 4 on mac or the snip tool on windows, then save that image and re convert.

i know, hack job, but it should work. let me know!

Comment: with HTML tag base64 tiff string is not viewable.